# 14.04 LTS 64 Bits booting trouble

Tags: boot, 14.04

When I try to boot Ubuntu, first I get the grub options and then I choose  to boot. After this, the screen gets full of 1111111111111 and then continues to Ubuntu logo with some commands that are displayed at the same time. At the end it just doesn't boot.
The only way I can get Ubuntu to boot is by pressing shift before 11111111 happens.
It wasn't like this before, but I had a try on Windows 8.1 and when I decided to  reinstall Ubuntu from the beginning I got the problem. I have already tried those options that appear when pressing F6 during process and those involving AHCI, Secure boot and some other from the BIOS with no positive results. So I would be grateful if someone knows how to solve this little big problem. I like Ubuntu and want it to go smooth. Thanks a lot! :-)

Dell Inspiron 3420
Core i5
4 Gb RAM
Images: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1CF426C9CF080ABC%21159

Comment: Did you try reinstalling grub? Once booted into Ubuntu run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (assuming that your boot disk is `/dev/sda`).

Comment: Thanks @sumwale but it didn't work. I reinstalled grub and still got the same problem. Actually I have reinstalled several times Ubuntu and twice OpenSuse with no positive results.

Comment: Ok from the images you uploaded the code printed on screen looks to be that of `Home` key (e.g. from a booted machine start plain "dash" on terminal and press `Home` and that has the same code as this). Could it just be that your `Home` key on laptop keyboard is stuck causing the problem?

Comment: Actually graphical terminal shows some other code for `Home` key but if you go in text mode e.g. `Ctrl-Alt-F1`, then the `Home` key shows `^[[1~` code as seen from your boot images.